# display large text file in textblock for windows phone 8 apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I used this code the display the text into my textblock :

```
private async void textblock1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder assetFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFile assetFile = await assetFolder.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\asset.txt");

        String assetText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(assetFile);

        List<String> lines = assetText.Split(new Char[] { ',' }).ToList();

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (String line in lines)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }

        textblock1.Text = sb.ToString();


    }
```

but the file is very large it it takes too long to load it .
is there a way to split the text to many textblocks using a code ? or should i split them myself ?
also is this code completely correct ? or there is mistakes in it ?

Answer (score 0):

what about using ItemsControl with VirtualizingStackPanel as ItemsPanel?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
String assetText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(assetFile);
List<String> lines = assetText.Split(new Char[] { ',' }).ToList();
ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = lines;
```

Comment: this code i used is working just fine , but i need to know how can i split the large text file with codes , so is it possible ?

Comment: you code is slow, because it takes long to render entire file in textblock.  I have split each line into separate TextBlock (ItemsControl takes care of createing textblock foreach item) and VirtualizingStackPanel renders only few lines that are currently visible. It should improve performane significantly.